# Does Microsoft.SqlServer.Types require a SQL Server Licence?

Tags: .net, sql-server

Do I need a SQL Server license to use the following package?

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/

I'm guessing not as I could install Express and not use the database.

Comment: "Allows you to use SQL Server spatial types on a machine without SQL Server installed".   If you are accessing a server as a client is a separate  issue and would need a valid client license.

Comment: The license is posted on nuget: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/eula/microsoft_sql_server_2012_microsoft_clr_eng.htm . I would think, however, that these types are specifically tailored for *communicating* with SQL Server, and if you're only interested in writing spatial (geo) software, there may be much better libraries out there for you.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation? At present, I only need to convert well known binary to get a lat long.